# Objective-C ARC and longjmp

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, lua, automatic-ref-counting, setjmp

**What is the best practice for mixing Objective-C ARC with `longjmp`?**

I am using Lua as scripting language, and my platform exports custom library for scripts. Entry points do check arguments with `luaL_checkinteger(L, 2)` (among others), which, in turn, may call `luaL_typerror(L, 2, ...)`, that is implemented in Lua with `setjmp`/`longjmp`. As far as I know, ARC simply auto-generates `retain`/`release` code, but what happens if it `longjmp`s out of scope? Will this code leak on mistyped arguments?

```
static int
set_tag(lua_State *L)
{
    NSControl *control = (__bridge NSControl *)lua_topointer(L, 1);
    [control setTag:(NSInteger)luaL_checkinteger(L, 2)]; // may longjmp!
    return 0;
}
```

In the snippet above, `control` will be temporarily retained by ARC, but with `longjmp`s uncatchable nature, corresponding release call may never happen. On the other hand, *all arguments* may be checked *before* assigning to `control` variable.

```
static int
set_tag(lua_State *L)
{
    NSInteger tag = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2); // may longjmp!
    NSControl *control = (__bridge NSControl *)lua_topointer(L, 1);
    [control setTag:tag];
    return 0;
}
```

Does it resolve [potential] leak above? Are there better ways to do this?

UPDATE: `longjmp` only unwinds to Lua internals, and never crosses any system code, except for Lua source (which is aware), and my entry points (which I hope are aware).

I'm pretty sure that second snippet does right, but I need kind of formal proof.

---

**LATE UPDATE:**

LuaJIT implements dwarf2-compatible errors, so they are just like C++ exceptions. Pass `-fobjc-arc-exceptions` compiler flag to arc-enabled sources with Lua code and any retained object will be released on any `lua_error`. Nothing to worry about now! You are still not allowed to throw errors across Cocoa runtime, though.

I recall that original Lua may be compiled with exceptions too, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't really matter if ARC is in use or not;  any `setjmp`/`longjmp` that jumps over any frame of code from the system frameworks will yield undefined behavior (for the same reason that exceptions cannot be used for recoverable error handling).

So, yes, that code *might* leak.  *Might* because it depends on whether the compiler emits a `retain`/`release` in that block and where.   *Might* also because whether the compiler emits `retain`/`release` will be impacted by the optimization level and, over time, the version of the compiler.

> `longjmp` only unwinds to Lua internals, and never crosses any system
>   code, except for Lua source (which is aware), and my entry points
>   (which I hope are aware).

That is helpful. As long as you structure your entry points such that they *never* intermingle system scope with Lua jumpable scopes, you *should* be OK.   I would recommend turning off ARC in the source files where you have to manage this (and, of course, put the ObjC->Lua interface into a nicely encapsulated bit of implementation so the rest of your code can be ARC clean).

Consider, though, that there is non-obvious risk:

```
for(id x in anArray) {
    ... lua call that causes longjmp ...
}
```

The above would cause lua to "jump over" system code.   Same goes for `enumerateWithBlock:`, KVO, Notification handlers, etc...

You're going to have to think very *very* carefully about every potential stack trigger by a call from Lua into your code.  If that call triggers any kind of automated behavior on the part of the system that could then call Lua API that could trigger a `longjmp`, all bets are off.

Comment: `longjmp` can't escape Lua call stack, of course. Thank you for the answer, but it's different case. I will update my question.

Comment: @user3125367 Yes, but can `longjmp` *jump over* a frame of Objective-C code?  Sounds like it can if it can short circuit out of a method body as you've described and that, therein, is both your problem and a subset of the exception problem.

Comment: The only dangerous place is my entry point. I was asking what is the best practice to avoid leaks, why all you guys scare me with exceptions and jumping over places that are not part of my question? Is second snippet ok or is it still dangerous, given I group longjmps *before* any arc code? That's all I need to know.

Comment: @user3125367 We are jumping on it because we don't know the implementation details of the Lua interpreter that you are using and, thus, are giving you generic answers.  Your clarifications help.

Answer (score 1):

`longjmp()` may cause crashes or leaks in ARC. Arranging the code so `longjmp()` and ARC don't interfere is difficult.

If the `longjmp()` is only for a fatal error path and you expect to halt the process in response then you may be able to ignore the problem. This is what ARC does with C++/ObjC exceptions by default. ARC code is expected to leak when exceptions are thrown. There's a compiler option to enable the clean up code for exceptions, but that hurts performance.

If the `longjmp()` is not a process-killing error then your best option is to turn off ARC in any code that may be skipped by a `longjmp()` call.

Comment: Why is it difficult? In my case, or overall? I am grouping jumping checks at top of function, and then do regular objc tasks. If check jumps, arc doesn't have a chance to retain anything.

Comment: Note that ARC may retain the incoming parameters. If you have no parameters of ARC-aware types then what you describe might work.